# How to get first time field occurs in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know how to find the first time an occurrence appears in a table. In this case when check become 1

```
---------------------------
Client Id   | Check | Week
---------------------------
1             0       1
3             1       1
1             0       2
1             1       3
3             1       2
```

Assuming this is the entire table the result of the query should give me

```
-----------------
Client id    | week
-----------------
1              3
3              1
```

Check can only be 0 or 1
Thanks

Comment: `the first time an occurrence appears in a table` an occurance of what?

Comment: Typing from mobile. I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT client_id, MIN(Week) AS first_occur
FROM table
WHERE check = 1
GROUP BY client_id
```

Comment: Cheers. Makes sense. If i have the year field, how would you modify this? Given the fact i will get the same week number many times

Comment: Add year in the group by.